Android Studio: "Unable to find a device matching the provided destination specifier" when running ios simulator (Flutter)
When trying to run my Flutter project on iOS simulator through Android Studio, I get this error:
Uncategorized (Xcode): Unable to find a device matching the provided destination specifier:
    { id:xxx }

The requested device could not be found because no available devices matched the request.

Available destinations for the "Runner" scheme:
    { platform:macOS, arch:arm64, variant:Designed for [iPad,iPhone], id:xxx, name:My Mac }
    { platform:iOS, id:dvtdevice-DVTiPhonePlaceholder-iphoneos:placeholder, name:Any iOS Device }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:dvtdevice-DVTiOSDeviceSimulatorPlaceholder-iphonesimulator:placeholder, name:Any iOS Simulator Device }

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPad (10th generation).

This worked earlier today and I think it was upgrading Flutter the broke it. Same error happens for all my Flutter projects.
Running the project through Xcode works perfectly! Also running through Android Studio to real device works.

Flutter version: 3.25.5
Xcode version: 16.1
Mac: Apple M1 Pro, Sequoia 15.1.1
Android Studio version: Meerkat | 2024.3.1 Nightly

Flutter doctor
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.24.5, on macOS 15.1.1 24B91 darwin-arm64, locale en-NO)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 16.1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[!] Android Studio (version unknown)
    ✗ Unable to determine Android Studio version.
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2024.3)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.80.0)
[✓] Connected device (6 available)
[✓] Network resources

All the things I have tried without success

flutter upgrade/clean/get
Delete Pods & Podfile.lock and pod deintegrate/install --repo-update
Making sure I have the newest Xcode and iOS installed
Opening different simulators with different iOS
Change target to Debug in Xcode
Change destination of Derived Data in Xcode
Change "supported platforms" from Iphoneos to iOS in Xcode
New Runner Scheme... in Xcode
Delete all Derived Data and rm -R ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Caches
sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer and sudo xcodebuild -runFirstLaunch
flutter downgrade
flutter channel stable/master + flutter upgrade
Making sure I have only one instance of Android Studio and Xcode
Re-clone repo
Reinstalled Xcode completely
Reinstalled Android Studio completely

Things I have not tried, but seriously considering

Throw my Mac out of the window
Throw myself out of the window
Quit my job, move to a desert island and start a 100% non-technical farm

Sidenote: Seems like Android studio struggles with finding/listing the iOS devices and if I click "Refresh", it takes a long time for the open simulators to appear.
If anyone out there has found a solution to this recently, please reach out!!!

After I did all of the above without success, I restarted my Mac and it suddenly worked...
Edit: New day, and I get the same error. Restart did the trick again. I guess I gotta restart my Mac daily now...
